# What does the + sign mean at the end of a calculation result?

Tags: notation, packing-problem

I discovered yesterday the [Square packing in a square problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_packing_in_a_square), and I ended up on [this page](https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/squinsqu/) that shows the proven answers for the first 89 values of $n$.

But at the end of some answers, we can see a plus sign:

$s = \frac{17}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{7}}{2} = 9.822+$

What does this sign mean in this context?

Comment: My guess would be "There's more digits and we truncated them". Personally I would use an ellipsis like $9.822...$

Comment: @student91 Also noting that it's $9.8229...$ so the correct rounding should be $9.823$, so it's indeed a truncation and not rounding.

Comment: This makes sense, thanks!